# Why VBA Code for Enable/Disable Buttons doesn't work?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Numeric field in a table. the field named "Pr330USD"
in a form, control source of a textbox named "PrEvFees" has been linked to that field.

I have also two buttons named:

OpenReportFRR

OpenFRRDraft

for opening two different Reports.

I wrote below codes aforementioned buttons:

```
Private Sub PrEvFees_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.PrEvFees.Value >= 300 Then
        OpenReportFRR.Enabled = True
        OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = False
    Else
        OpenReportFRR.Enabled = False
        OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = True
    End If

    DoCmd.Save
    DoCmd.RefreshRecord

End Sub
```

Problems are:
After insert an amount (less than 300 USD or above) the buttons doesn't change their situations and also Refresh command doesn't work (I have on the line included "DoCmd.RefreshRecord" a yellow alert).

any idea is thanks full.

Comment: Protip: try to [edit] your title so that someone having a similar problem would type it in a Google search box and find your question (and its answers!). As it stands, this title applies to virtually every single VBA question ever asked on this site.

Comment: The `BeforeUpdate` event is called before an update is made to an existing record that is loaded in the form. However you said after _insert_ an amount is it a new record or an already existing one?

Comment: Move the code to the _AfterUpdate_ event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, thank you...
especially Mat's Mug and litelite :)

Finally, the codes with removing a line (last line about "Refresh" order) works correctly. the final codes are below:

Private Sub PrEvFees_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

```
If Me.PrEvFees.Value >= 300 Then

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = True
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = False

Else

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = False
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = True

End If

    DoCmd.Save

End Sub
```